# How to use XSLT to copy value of a parent element to multiple children nodes?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file that needs transformed for import to a financial system. The "location" is referenced only once at the beginning, followed by records (usually a few hundred), which I've transformed to identify as Debit or Credit, but I need to pull the location info from the top of the file so it is listed in each record for import.

Source File:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gldata>
    <FacilityData>
        <Corp>Fabrikam Group</Corp>
        <FacilityID>26</FacilityID>
        <CustomerLocationID>640</CustomerLocationID>
        <Region>PA</Region>
        <District>Springfield</District>
        <transaction>
            <EntryID>12345</EntryID>
            <TransactionDate>07-24-2023</TransactionDate>
            <ServiceDate>
            </ServiceDate>
            <TransactionType>40</TransactionType>
            <TransDescription>Desription Generic</TransDescription>
            <AccountNumber>1010-00</AccountNumber>
            <Currency>USD</Currency>
            <AccountType>A</AccountType>
            <BatchID>2351</BatchID>
            <TransactionDetail>
                <Amount>628.00</Amount>
                <Type>DRAmount</Type>
            </TransactionDetail>
        </transaction>
       </FacilityData>
</gldata>
.
.
```

My current XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TransactionDetail">
    <xsl:element name="{Type}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I need:

```
<transaction>
    <EntryID>12345</EntryID>
    <TransactionDate>07-24-2023</TransactionDate>
    <ServiceDate>
    </ServiceDate>
    <TransactionType>40</TransactionType>
    <TransDescription>Desription Generic</TransDescription>
    <AccountNumber>1010-00</AccountNumber>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    <AccountType>A</AccountType>
    <BatchID>2351</BatchID>
    <TransactionDetail>
        <Amount>628.00</Amount>
        <Type>DRAmount</Type>
                <CustomerLocationID>640</CustomerLocationID>
    </TransactionDetail>
</transaction>
```

Obviously, I can deal with extra info, but nothing I've been able to do will pull the info from the top of the form and copy it to each record. I do need it under "TransactionDetail" because many "Transaction" records have multiple detail lines which are imported as separate line items.

Any help is greatly appreciated!! I'm not great at XML but I feel like I'm making this much harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
<xsl:template match="TransactionDetail">
    <xsl:element name="{Type}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::FacilityData/CustomerLocationID"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

A more efficient method might retrieve the `CustomerLocationID` *once* when at the `FacilityData` level, and store it in variable or a parameter to be used at the `TransactionDetail` level.

If you are limited to **XSLT 1.0**, this could look something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform with pass-thru param -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:param name="custLocID"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            <xsl:with-param name="custLocID" select="$custLocID"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FacilityData">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            <xsl:with-param name="custLocID" select="CustomerLocationID"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TransactionDetail">
    <xsl:param name="custLocID"/>
    <xsl:element name="{Type}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$custLocID"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ugh, ancestor is what I couldn’t find and why I kept not being able to jump back that many levels. 

I’m not too worried about efficiency as these aren’t too huge of files, and there’s a chance of them ending up scattered with multiple facilities in one file so I think I’m better in the long run to avoid variables and having to reset them, etc. Thank you so much for the fast response!

Comment: It's only 2 levels up, so you could have done `<xsl:copy-of select="../../CustomerLocationID"/>`.  --- There is no need to reset variables (and you couldn't even if you wanted to, since XSLT variables are immutable). And you can have any number of facilities; each facility will pass down its own parameter to its descendants.